# Update data on page without refreshing on with Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When I try to add a friend, button is loading and show up again instead of Waiting for response, but after refresh the page it works.

```
   methods: {

        add_friend(){


            this.loading = true

            this.$http.get('/add_friend/' + this.profile_user_id)

                .then( (r) => {

                    if(r.body == 1)

                        this.status = 'waiting'
                        this.loading = false

                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` condition misses curly braces. This is only valid for one-line statements but not for multi-line.

```
if(r.body == 1) {
    this.status = 'waiting';
    this.loading = false;
}
```

Check also if `r.body` contains `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning `body` from your laravel controller, then your http block in vue, should look like this:

```
this.$http.get('/add_friend/' + this.profile_user_id)

            .then( (r) => { // you can also use destructing
                const data = r.data;

                if(data.body == 1)

                    this.status = 'waiting'
                    this.loading = false

            })
```